# Garbled text in Adobe Pro DC

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. I was sent a timesheet from another employee. When I opened the document, it showed the text in the image below. I have been able to open it using Adobe Reader. However, when I try to open it with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC, the text is garbled. No other PDF file is garbled, and when I open it using Microsoft Edge it seems to work just fine.

I have tried running updates on the software, but it says, "no updates are available." I have also tried performing a installation repair, but I continue to get the same results. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to change the garbled text back to normal? Also, can someone explain to me why it happens?

[image: garbageText]

Comment: Try a different .pdf file, do you get the same results? I would empty all the TEMP folders, then empty (remove then replace) the paging file (set to none, reboot then set to allow the system to create the size), then reboot again. The pagefile may be corrupt.

Comment: Is it possible to share a copy of the document? It looks like the fonts that the PDF requires are not on your system - and the only way to check this is to take a look inside the PDF.

Comment: So, I had the strangest thing happen and I don't know why. I went back to the employee who was having the problem to try to fix it using the instructions I got from Adobe. When I opened the same PDF, I was able to read it in cleartext. It appears the problem fixed itself. I'm stumped on this one because I don't know the why.